# Segmentation fault in mongocxx driver

Tags: c++, mongodb, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to connect to my MongoDB instance using the mongocxx driver. I installed the latest version following [this](http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/) guide. My CMakeLists looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.2)
project(example)

find_package(mongocxx 3.6.2 REQUIRED)
find_package(bsoncxx 3.6.2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(example src/main.cpp)

# Link dependencies
target_link_libraries(example mongo::bsoncxx_shared)
target_link_libraries(example mongo::mongocxx_shared)
```

In my main function, I have the following simple code:

```cpp
int main()
{
    mongocxx::instance inst{}; // This should be done only once.
    mongocxx::uri uri("mongodb://10.10.10.123:27017");
    mongocxx::client client(uri);
    mongocxx::database _db = client["test"];

    using namespace bsoncxx::builder::basic;
    
    auto doc = make_document(kvp("ismaster", 1));
    auto res = _db.run_command(doc.view()); <----- Segmentation Fault
}
```

Whenever I try to communicate with the MongoDB, using for instance `insert_one`, or `run_command`, I receive this segmentation fault.

Is this a problem in my code, a library linking problem (I ensured all my packages are from the same version 3.6.2, but it might be that I missed something), or could there be another issue that I'm not seeing?

**EDIT**:
I have the following backtrace:
[image: backtrace]

The segmentation fault happens here:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
mongoc_topology_scanner_valid (ts=ts@entry=0x0) at /root/dev/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.6.2/build/mongo-c-driver-1.17.4/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-topology-scanner.c:413
413    return ts->nodes != NULL;
```

**EDIT 2**:
A minimal example is:

```
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/stdx.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>

int main()
{
    mongocxx::instance inst{}; // This should be done only once.
    mongocxx::uri uri("mongodb://10.10.10.132:27017/");
    mongocxx::client client(uri);
    mongocxx::database db = client["test"];

    using namespace bsoncxx::builder::basic;    
    auto doc = make_document(kvp("ismaster", 1));
    auto res = db.run_command(doc.view());
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling:
 `gcc -o example -I/usr/local/include/mongocxx/v_noabi -I/usr/local/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi -L/usr/local/lib/mongocxx -L/usr/local/lib/bsoncxx main.cpp`

Comment: "this segmentation fault" -- I don't see one. What's the backtrace? Can you provide a [mcve] including the commandline used to compile it?

Comment: @laurensvm Do you have access to the source code?  If you do, then you can pinpoint exactly where things go wrong instead of just relying on a backtrace.

Comment: The mongoc source code is open source ([here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver)), and I see that some value is NULL, I just can't figure out what is causes, also when following the backtrace in the source code.

Comment: Tried it on Fedora 33 x86_64 with MongoDB installed from upstream according to https://fedoramagazine.org/how-to-get-mongodb-server-on-fedora/ (and sure changing the server URL in your example to 127.0.0.1) and it works without any issue. Both with valgrind and with -fsanitize=address (but sure the libmongocxx has not been recompiled with -fsanitize=address). mongodb-org-4.2.12-1.el8.x86_64 + mongo-cxx-driver-devel-3.4.1-4.fc33.x86_64

Comment: Thank you Jan. Then I assume I did something wrong when installing the mongocxx packages.

Comment: I reinstalled the mongocxx driver following very closely the instructions given http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/. Built both libmongoc and mongocxx from the latest tarball. I’m still receiving the same segmentation fault. Any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: Load the program into a debugger (gdb/visual c++ etc.) and follow the stack up from the crash site, tracing where that null pointer came from.